# Ansible: Include task only when server is not in group

Tags: include, ansible, groupname

I have some groups with different names and something like "raw-webservers", "raw-db", ...
Now I want to include a playbook if the server is in a group which begins with 'raw-*' (works) and include another playbook if the server is not in a group which begins with 'raw-'. I have not been able to figure out how to do the last thing by specifying only a subset of the group.

```
- include_tasks: change_password.yml
  when: "'raw-' not in group_names"   # works only with complete group names


- include_tasks: change_password_raw.yml
  when: "group_names | search('raw-')"   # works
```

I've tried 'when: "group_names | not search('raw-')"' but it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a few methods. Here is a sample playbook showing two such methods. One using select and the other using search.

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "hello world using select"
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      when: group_names | select('match','raw-*') | list | length  > 0

    - debug:
        msg: "hello world using search"
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      when: group_names | join(" ") is search('raw-')
```

You'll see here that search [works on strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) and not lists, hence why the join.

Alternative to this, you can use another group for this. For example, your inventory could add the following.

```
[raw:children]
db
```

And this could be tested as `'raw' in group_names`.

Comment: Thanks! "group_names | join(" ") is search('raw-')" and "group_names | join(" ") is not search('raw-')" works great!